# Magento 1.9 special price showed after expiration

Tags: magento-1.9, special-price

I have an issue with the special price. I set expiration date and after expiration, the price showed is the special price.

I tried to reindex price and clean the cache but showed always the special price.

Please help, how can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set valid values for the **special price from date** and **special price to date** attributes for the products.

Also, check whether you have any promotional **catalog price rule** applied for setting discount on products.

Another possible source of special prices is **customer group prices** (configured for each product as well).

After checking, please do the **reindexing** and flush Magento's **cache** to see the reflection.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks your answare, the problem I had yesterday disappeared, I do not know exactly why, but I noticed that this morning the price is correct, don't show the special price.
I can only imagine that the system has considered the end date set yesterday at 12/27/2017 and today that is the day 12/28/2017 has updated the value.
Precise also that the tests I had done, I had also made all the checks of the values, and controlled every view of the store being multilingual.